# How to count items in plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I got a question how i can count items in my plist file. I tried:

```
NSString *bundlePathofPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Mything" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:bundlePathofPlist];

    NSArray *dataFromPlist = [dict valueForKey:@"some"];

    for(int i =0;i<[dataFromPlist count];i++)
    {
        //NSLog(@"%@",[dataFromPlist objectAtIndex:i]);
        [self setTableData:[dataFromPlist count]];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@", tableData);
```

But on this line an error appears:

```
    [self setTableData:[dataFromPlist count]];

Implicit conversion of 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'NSArray *' is disallowed with ARC
```

and warning:

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') to parameter of type 'NSArray *';
```

Comment: @Popeye Thank you for removing that unnecessary [xcode] tag.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I do believe even though I removed it, it has been added back in by Frenck.

Comment: @Frenck please dont add the Xcode tag again. For this question it is irrelevant. It would only produces clutter and noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `setTableData` takes an `NSArray` instance. You need to prepare an array upfront in a loop, and then set it once, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i =0;i<[dataFromPlist count];i++)
{
    //NSLog(@"%@",[dataFromPlist objectAtIndex:i]);
    [data addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dataFromPlist objectAtIndex:i] count]]];
}
[self setTableData:data];
```

This assumes that your `setTableData` method expects an array of `NSNumber` instances wrapping `int`s.

Comment: This code is going to give you `count` instances of the same number, which is `count`. Surely that's not correct?

Comment: @KevinBallard You are right, I copy-pasted the snippet from the OP without thinking of what it does. It should be fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using `[dataFromPlist count]` inside your for loop, which makes no sense. You probably meant `[dataFromPlist objectAtIndex:i]`.

Or, more idiomatically,

```
for (NSArray *elt in dataFromPlist) {
    [self setTableData:elt];
}
```

Although I do have to wonder why you're calling -setTableData: over and over with different elements.